# Gmail email contents transfer to google spreadsheet

Tags: gmail, spreadsheet

I ask for help. Help me to finish the script. It is necessary to transfer the contents of mail gmail, to Google table. There is a script, but it only transfers the date and subject of the letter, and the message itself does not. Help, that it is possible to correct. Thanks

```
 function getGmailData() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var threads = GmailApp.search("is:unread in:inbox", 0, 1);
  for (var t=0; t<threads.length; t++) {
    sheet.appendRow([threads[t].getDate(), threads[t].getFirstMessageSubject()])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a following modification?

#### Modification points :

1. In order to retrieve messages from `threads`, `getMessages()` is used.
2. In order to retrieve each message from messages retrieved by [`getMessages()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#getMessages()), it retrieves using one more "for loop".
3. For each mail, the Date, From, Subject and Body can be retrieved by [`getDate()`, `getFrom()`, `getSubject()` and `getPlainBody()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message), respecrively.

#### Modified script :

```
function getGmailData() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var threads = GmailApp.search("is:unread in:inbox", 0, 1);
  var res = [];
  for (var t=0; t<threads.length; t++) {
    var msgs = threads[t].getMessages();
    for (var u=0; u<msgs.length; u++) {
      var m = msgs[u];
      res.push([m.getDate(), m.getFrom(), m.getSubject(), m.getPlainBody()]);
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

### Edit :

When you want to retrieve mails from today, you can use `newer_than:` and `after:` operators.

#### In the case of using `newer_than:`

```
var threads = GmailApp.search("newer_than:1d in:inbox", 0, 1);
```

#### In the case of using `after:`

```
var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'yyyy/MM/dd');
var threads = GmailApp.search("after:" + today + " in:inbox", 0, 1);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you very much helped. How can I make it come from the last letter, many old letters import.

Comment: @Anna Manshylina If you want to retrieve old mails, you can use search operators. For example, you want to retrieve mails before Jan. 1, 2017, you can use ``before:2017/01/01``. You can see other operators [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190). If I misunderstand your comment, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No, I want to receive letters from today. Probably need to change something in the line var threads = GmailApp.search("is:unread in:inbox", 0, 1);

Comment: @Anna Manshylina I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I updated my answer. Please confirm it.

Comment: @Anna Manshylina Was your problem solved? If you have problems, feel free to tell me.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help))). Letters are imported into the Google table. But many takes is

Comment: @Anna Manshylina Do you want to control the number of imported mails to spreadsheet? Is my understanding correct? I apologize for being my poor English skill.

Comment: Yes, I'm good at importing everything. But there are a lot of duplicate letters. thank you for your help)

Comment: @Anna Manshylina In order to check the duplicate letters, can you tell me about the duplicate part? For example, subject, from, title and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Well, I still have letters for yesterday. I did as you wrote

Comment: function getGmailData() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'yyyy/MM/dd');
var threads = GmailApp.search("after:" + today + " in:inbox", 0, 1);
  var res = [];
  for (var t=0; t<threads.length; t++) {
    var msgs = threads[t].getMessages();
    for (var u=0; u<msgs.length; u++) {
      var m = msgs[u];
      res.push([m.getDate(),  m.getPlainBody()]);
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
}

Comment: @Anna Manshylina Thank you for adding the information. But it seems that the script you showed is the same to my answer. Can I ask you about your current problem? I'm sorry for my poor English skill.